# Не срабатывает скрипт jQuery

Tags: jquery

Подскажите, почему у меня не срабатывает такой скрипт, он должен вставлять текст в контейнере `<p></p>` до тега `<span>` в этот кусок HTML-кода

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("span#nc_capfld_2431").before("<p><i>Для конвейера указать:</i></p>");
</script>

<span style='' id='nc_capfld_2431'>3. Технологический участок, где планируется сепарация:</span>
<input name='f_Techn3' type='text' maxlength='255' size='50' value='' />
```

но скрипт не срабатывает. Подскажите, почему?

Comment:     span#nc_capfld_2431
     id='nc_capfld_2430'

Немного разные цифры как на мой взгляд)

**UPD**: Были...

Comment: Сорри, ошиблась)) но спан с Id nc_capfld_2430 там тоже есть, всё равно перед ним не вставляет.

Comment: Ответ вам ниже!

Comment: Я там уже откомментировала - так тоже не срабатывает, увы

Comment: Ахах ) Всегда проверяйте, подключение либы ) Дело в том что у Вас может быть проблема и со слешем в src ^^ <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script> и попросту либа не подключится, если вы не юзаете Denwer на локальном хосте, или так что. Если вы просто запускаете файл index.html, то стоит убрать слеш и посмотреть. Всё будет работать ;) Таже нужно мнежду тегами <script> прописать $(document).ready(function(){
 здесь ваш код; });

Comment: да подключена там либа, и я знаю про слэши) у меня какая-то проблема с браузером, в гугл хром не отрабатывают скрипты jQuery, в других браузерах все работает, в гугл хром - только посл очистки кэша и куки.

Answer (score 2):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("span#nc_capfld_2430").before("<p><i>Для конвейера указать:</i></p>");
    }); 
</script>
```

и будет вам счастье..

Comment: так в том что и дело, что нет, так я уже тоже пробовала, и все равно не срабатывает.

Comment: все, спасибо, вопрос снимается, все было правильно на самом деле, но на моем компе тупит гугл хром и некорректно отображает результат работы скриптов. приходится всё время чистить кэш. на самом деле, всё работало, файерфокс все показывает, гугл хром после очистки кэша - тоже.

Answer (score 2):

Данный код работает, проверил.

- Разница - jQuery последний (не суть,
     ибо просто не нашел вашей версии)
- вызов скрипта перемещен после места
     срабатывания (т.к. у вас он 
     вызывается до загрузки HTML body, 
     т.е. нужно было или как было указано 
     вызвать его по событию или как я)
- все файлы находятся в одной папке

  ```
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <span style='' id='nc_capfld_2431'>3. Технологический участок, где планируется сепарация:</span>
      <input name='f_Techn3' type='text' maxlength='255' size='50' value='' /><br />
      <script type="text/javascript">
          $("span#nc_capfld_2431").before("<p><i>Для конвейера указать:</i></p>");
      </script>
  </body>
  ```

Comment: чет лажа с форматированием, вроде отмечаю как код, один фиг каша выходит, сорри

Comment: короч, форматтер не любит тэг <html></html>, придется добавить вам самому

Comment: код Александра Молофеева (выше) тоже работает, только там указан не тот id - #nc_capfld_2431 вместо #nc_capfld_2430

Comment: и 'span' в селекторе вовсе ни к чему (id является уникальными идентификатором) $("span#nc_capfld_2431") == $("#nc_capfld_2431")

Comment: Да все это верно, я понимаю)) но не срабатывает, блин. Форму у меня формирует цмс, поэтому вставить скрипт после спана или просто тупо в коде в нужное место вставить <p><i>Для конвейера указать:</i></p> я не могу. поэтому и использую jquery
вариант <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#nc_capfld_2431").before("<p><i>Для конвейера указать:</i></p>");
    }); 
</script> то же не срабатывает.

Comment: все, спасибо, вопрос снимается, все было правильно на самом деле, но на моем компе тупит гугл хром и некорректно отображает результат работы скриптов. приходится всё время чистить кэш. на самом деле, всё работало, файерфокс все показывает, гугл хром после очистки кэша - тоже.